# How to get the unique id of an ad from google analytics api

Tags: php, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I am newcomer to the [Google Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/), there is any way to extract the **AdId** form this api, [Google adwords api](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/) provides a `unique id` of each Ad.

I have been able to extract `ga:adwordsCampaignID` and `ga:adwordsAdGroupID` from Google Analytics API. I am having trouble finding an option for **Ad Id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this time the Ad id is not available though the Google analytics API.  Currently only the following are available to you to extract though the Google Analytics api:

> ga:adGroup ga:adSlot ga:adSlotPosition ga:adDistributionNetwork
>   ga:adMatchType ga:adKeywordMatchType ga:adMatchedQuery
>   ga:adPlacementDomain ga:adPlacementUrl ga:adFormat ga:adTargetingType
>   ga:adTargetingOption ga:adDisplayUrl ga:adDestinationUrl
>   ga:adwordsCustomerID ga:adwordsCampaignID ga:adwordsAdGroupID
>   ga:adwordsCreativeID ga:adwordsCriteriaID ga:adQueryWordCount
>   ga:isTrueViewVideoAd

New dimensions and metrics are being added from time to time.  You may want to check this page and see if it is added in the future. [Adwords - Dimensions & Metrics Reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=adwords)

Comment: Your answer is helpful, Thank You

Answer (score 2):

In Google Analytics the dimension `ga:adwordsCreativeID` [(API Reference)](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=adwords&jump=ga_adwordscreativeid) is equivalent to AdWords API `Ad.id` and is likely to match your requirements

Comment: `ga:adwordsCreativeID` is not much helpful for my purpose, But it was helpful for some other fixes.

Thank you :)